# Different output while using node and node pointer in structure

Tags: c++, stack

I am writing code to create a stack and know whether the stack is empty or not.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct stack
{
    /* data */
    int size;
    int top;
    int *arr;
};

// Functions
int isEmpty(struct stack ptr)
{
    if (ptr.top == -1)
    {
        /* code */
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

int isFull(struct stack ptr)
{
    if (ptr.top == ptr.size - 1)
    {
        /* code */
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

int main()
{

    struct stack s; // Stack is used as pointer for ease.
    s.size = 80;
    s.top = -1;
    s.arr = (int *)malloc(s.size * sizeof(int));

    // Pushing an element manually
    s.arr[0] = 7;
    s.top++;

    if (isEmpty(s))
    {
        /* code */
        printf("The stack is empty.\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("The stack is not empty.\n");
    }
    
    if (isFull(s))
    {
        /* code */
        printf("The stack is full.\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("The stack is not full.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This code goes very well. But when I use Node *(pointer) for the stack, program doesn't execute completely.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct stack
{
    /* data */
    int size;
    int top;
    int *arr;
};

// Functions
int isEmpty(struct stack *ptr)
{
    if (ptr->top == -1)
    {
        /* code */
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

int isFull(struct stack *ptr)
{
    if (ptr->top == ptr->size - 1)
    {
        /* code */
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

int main()
{

    struct stack *s; // Stack is used as pointer for ease.
    s->size = 8;
    s->top = -1;
    s->arr = (int *)malloc(s->size * sizeof(int));

    // Pushing an element manually
    // s->arr[0] = 7;
    // s->top++;

    if (isEmpty(s))
    {
        /* code */
        printf("The stack is empty.");
    }
    else{
        printf("The stack is not empty.");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Sometimes the code doesn't even run. And.....

Sometimes this shows an error like this:

> ```
>     c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
> ```
>
> cannot open output file Creation.exe: Permission denied
> collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Please help!!

Comment: `s` doesn't point to any object and you're dereferencing it which leads to undefined behavior in your 2nd code snippet.

Comment: Your second program executes undefined behavior just two lines in. Dereferencing indeterminate and/or null pointers is a fundamental no-no in C, and covered by even the most remedial C tomes in the chapter(s) on pointers and pointer management.

Comment: ***cannot open output file Creation.exe: Permission denied collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status*** Is probably caused by your antivirus or you were still debugging your previous executable when you tried to compile.

Answer (score 2):

The **problem** in the 2nd code snippet is that `s` is **uninitialized** meaning it is not pointing to any object and you're dereferencing it when you wrote `s->size`, `s->top` and `s->arr`, which leads to **undefined behavior**.

> **Undefined behavior** means anything<sup>1</sup> can happen *including but not limited to* the program giving your expected output. But **never rely**(or make conclusions based) on the output of a program that has undefined behavior.

So the output that you're seeing(maybe seeing) is a result of undefined behavior. And as i said **don't rely on the output** of a program that has UB. The program may just crash.

For example, [here](https://onlinegdb.com/neM5YAgJs) the program doesn't crash but [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/WeRFXTbWRVyYG8TZ) it crashes.

So the first step to make the program correct would be to remove UB. **Then and only then** you can start reasoning about the output of the program.

To **solve** this make sure that `s` points to a `stack` object before dereferencing it(s).

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>For a more technically accurate definition of undefined behavior see [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) where it is mentioned that: **there are no restrictions on the behavior of the program**.</sup>